# Do I install Wordpress from my Cpanel on https or http, if my website has valid certificate?

Tags: ssl

im about to install wordpress trought my cpanel, and it asks me do I want to install it on HTTP or https,
I checked, and my domain has valid SSL certificate? what should I do? install It on https or HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely HTTPS. There’s no benefit to not using it, if it’s available.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to use HTTPS is that it adds security to your website. It protects your site from hackers. They use techniques to steal your customer's sensitive information. Using HTTPS also gain your customer's trust.